# Naruto Shippūden Ultimate Ninja Storm 2: Tilting

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-2

I've read in various places that it is possible to perform a 'tilt' move with the characters in the Naruto Shippūden Ultimate Ninja Storm 2 game. I have two questions on this, as I can't find my information on it:

1. What exactly *is* tilting?
2. How do you actually perform a tilt in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Tilt is a combo that is available for every characters.

2) Yeah, the big thing that everyone never tells anyone is "Just nudge it, and the let go of the stick. Let it go to center. Then press O".

Steps:
1. Press stick in any direction slightly.
2. Let go of stick, letting it return to center. Don't hold it!
(This process is fluid, and happens within a second. )
3. Press O.

[Source](http://www.gamespot.com/naruto-shippuden-ultimate-ninja-storm-2/answers/tilting-233644/)

Other sources [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/982705-naruto-shippuden-ultimate-ninja-storm-2/answers?qid=234874) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/982706-/56832182).

Comment: Worked like a charm.